# Bind to Active Directory with S.DS.AccountManagement from outside the domain

Tags: active-directory, web-config, ldap

My machine is in domain A and I try to bind to domain B. 
There is no trust relation between them, in other domains where there is a trust relation there is no problem.

I use a form auth:

```
<add name="AMembershipProvider" 
     connectionUsername="TestDomain.intra\administrator"  
     connectionPassword="P@ssw0rd" 
     type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
     connectionStringName="Testinfofer.intraADService" 
     attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
```

I added domain B Domain Controller in my hosts file.

When I connect to domain B with Softerra LDAP Administrator is OK.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The exception was in my UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity method in my context parameter.

```
var domainContext = 
  new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
      model.Domeniu, domainContainer,ContextOptions.Negotiate);
```

I have not passed the user and the password, after I did that it was OK.

```
var domainContext = 
   new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
       model.Domeniu, domainContainer,
           ContextOptions.Negotiate,user,password);
```